# Can't get user input generated math product to output

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm in the process of trying to make an LED savings calculator (with inputs from a user via web page).  With code below, it successfully outputs existing fixtures' yearly electric use and the cost for this electric use.  But I can't figure out why it won't do the same for proposed fixtures.

If anyone can lend me a clue, that would be fantastic!

(Please note that I realize not all variables declared are yet in use.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>LED Savings Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>

<b>Electric utility rate</b>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Your electric utility rate ($/kWh):</td>
    <td><input id="elecRate" value="0.17" onchange="calculate();"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<b>Existing Lighting:</b>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Number of existing fixtures:</td>
    <td><input id="numExisting" onchange="calculate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Watts per fixture (include watts of bulbs or tubes, plus watts of      ballast):</td>
    <td><input id="wattsExisting" onchange="calculate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cost of bulbs or tubes, per fixture:</td>
    <td><input id="priceExisting" onchange="calculate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Lifespan of bulb or tube (rated hours):<br><br>
        (Typical incandescent: 1,000 - 2,000 hours.)</td>
    <td><input id="lifeExisting" onchange="calculate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Hours lights are on per day (average per fixture):</td>
    <td><input id="hoursOn" onchange="calculate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Days lights are on per week (average per fixture):</td>
    <td><input id="daysOn" onchange="calculate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total electric use per year (kWh):</td>
    <td><span id="kwhPerYearField"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total electric cost per year:</td>
    <td>$<span id="elecCostPerYearField"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<b>Proposed LED Lighting:</b>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Number of proposed LED fixtures:<br>(Note that often less LED  fixtures than existing fixtures are necessary to provide same lighting.)</td>
    <td><input id="numProposed" onchange="calculate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Watts per proposed LED fixture:<br></td>
    <td><input id="wattsProposed" onchange="calculate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cost of upgrade per proposed LED fixture ($):</td>
    <td><input id="costPerProposed" onchange="calculate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Lifespan (rated hours) per proposed LED bulb or tube:</td>
    <td><input id="lifeProposed" onchange="calculate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total electric use per year (kWh) (all proposed fixtures):</td>
    <td><span id="kwhPerYearProposedField"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total electric cost per year (all proposed fixtures):</td>
    <td>$<span id="elecCostPerYearProposedField"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script language="JavaScript">
function calculate(){
    <!-- Existing lighting: -->
    var numExisting = document.getElementById("numExisting").value;
    var wattsExisting = document.getElementById("wattsExisting").value;
    var priceExisting = document.getElementById("priceExisting").value;
    var lifeExisting = document.getElementById("lifeExisting").value;
    var elecRate = document.getElementById("elecRate").value;
    var hoursOn = document.getElementById("hoursOn").value;
    var daysOn = document.getElementById("daysOn").value;

    var kwhPerYearField = document.getElementById("kwhPerYearField");
    var elecCostPerYearField = document.getElementById("elecCostPerYearField");
    var kwhPerYear = (numExisting*wattsExisting*hoursOn*daysOn*52)/1000;
    kwhPerYearField.innerHTML = kwhPerYear.toString();
    elecCostPerYearField.innerHTML = (kwhPerYear*elecRate).toFixed(2);


    <!-- Proposed lighting: -->
    var numProposed = document.getElementById("numProposed").value;
    var wattsProposed = document.getElementById("wattsProposed").value;
    var costPerProposed = document.getElementById("costPerProposed").value;
    var lifeProposed = document.getElementById("lifeProposed").value;

    var kwhPerYearProposed = (numProposed*wattsProposed*hoursOn*daysOn*52)/1000;
    var kwhPerYearProposedField = document.getelementbyid("kwhPerYearProposedField");
    kwhPerYearProposedField.innerHTML = kwhPerYearProposed.toString();

    var elecCostPerYearProposedField = document.getElementById("elecCostPerYearProposedField");
    elecCostPerYearProposedField.innerHTML = (kwhPerYearProposed*elecRate).toFixed(2);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you bother to check the Javascript console for errors? You need to do some of your own debugging first. StackOverflow should be the **last** resort, not the first.

Comment: Yes, I debugged first.  I'm using WebStorm.  It didn't flag it.  Do you have a better suggestion for IDE to use?

Comment: I don't know about WebStorm (I use PhpStorm, the Mac version, but I never use its built-in debugger), but trying it in a real browser would have shown the error that @Halcyon pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getelementbyid is not a function

Change to `getElementbyId`. JavaScript is case**sensitive**.

```
var kwhPerYearProposedField = document.getelementbyid("kwhPerYearProposedField");
//                                     ^
```